# Alert in the mini cart if the minimum order is not reached (after clicking the checkout button)

Tags: magento2

At the moment Magento 2 after clicking the checkout button redirecting to editing cart page if minimum order is not reached. Is it possible to just give an alert message without redirecting?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you need to used this event.

Used this event observer to check checkAvailability()

checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

Used this event observer to used SendOrderId()

sales_order_place_after

Comment: didn't get anything